# Map two classes in runtime using column mapping information provided in a JSON file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have two Classes like this.

```
public class InputModel
{        
    public int studentid { get; set; }        
    public string studentname { get; set; }       
    public string studentcity { get; set; }
}

public class OutputModel
{
    public int StudentIDColumn { get; set; }
    public string StudentNameColumn { get; set; }
    public string StudentCityColumn { get; set; }
}
```

Now the requirement is like this:

I will receive an object of `InputModel` Class. From this, I need to create an object of `OutputModel` class.

It's simple if we use a library like AutoMapper. But the problem is, the Column-To-Column Mapping information will be supplied via a Json File like this:

```
{
  "studentid": "StudentIDColumn",
  "studentname": "StudentNameColumn",
  "studentcity": "StudentCityColumn"
}
```

Based on the JSON mapping data, I need to Map the columns in runtime and generate the Output class object.

I tried to map the two classes using Automapper. But I am not sure how to do it in runtime using the JSON file.

```
var MapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(c => 
            c.CreateMap<InputCSVModel, OutputIDMModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.StudentIDColumn, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.studentid))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.StudentNameColumn, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.studentname))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.StudentCityColumn, act => act.MapFrom(src => src.studentcity))
            );
            
var mapper = new Mapper(MapperConfig);                

OutputIDMModel outModel = mapper.Map<OutputIDMModel>(inputModel);
```

How can I achieve this?

It might be possible to do this with reflection, but I don't know how to implement that.

Comment: I would go with the reflection aproach. Read each JSON record and  get the value of the origin property in Input object, then Set that value in Output object property defined in the JSON record

Comment: It's easy to write some code to configure AM from that json using the non generic, type based, `CreateMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to read the JSON file and pass the strings in the automapper config like this.

```
var MapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
            c.CreateMap<InputModel, OutputModel>()
            .ForMember("StudentIDColumn", opt => opt.MapFrom("studentid"))
            .ForMember("StudentNameColumn", opt => opt.MapFrom("studentname"))
            .ForMember("StudentCityColumn", opt => opt.MapFrom("studentcity"))
            );
```